# mysql error inner join

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I used a query like

```
select a.email,b.vuid 
from user a
,inner join group b on a.uid = b.uid 
where a.email='xx@xx.de' and a.kid=1 and b.vid=29 
limit 1
```

but I always get this error.

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'inner join group b on a.uid = b.uid where a.email='xx@xx.de' at line 1

I think its because the inner join but I don't know really.. Could someone help me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove the `,` after `from user a`.

Your query should be:

```
select a.email,b.vuid
from user a
inner join group b
on a.uid = b.uid
where a.email='xx@xx.de'
    and a.kid=1 
    and b.vid=29
limit 1
```

Answer (score 2):

```
select a.email,b.vuid from user as a inner join group as b on ...
```

Of course you can omit the `as` keyword as demonstrated by @FrustratedWithFormsDesigner but in my opinion it is much more readable this way.

Comment: @Johan Thanks for commenting, could you show me the syntax error?

Comment: You have a ',' before 'inner join'

Comment: @Johan Thanks, I have already edited it out after I posted the answer. You could remove the downvote if you will.